# Referencing functions in a git repository

Tags: reactjs, git

I have some git libraries I am using for my app and using vscode. But I am a little unclear on how to reference these libraries and if I have to be specific in the 'from' part of not.

For example, my code below is something I copied from someone else code, and is at the top of my App.js file.

```
import {
  Board,
  BoardView,
} from 'cm-board';
```

Does vscode go search all subdirectories to find cm-board? Or, should I be using this instead:

```
import {
  Board,
  BoardView,
} from '../node-modules/cm-board';
```

And if I reference cm-board, does that also give me access to all files below cm-board too or do I have to import each one of those individually?

Comment: I don't quite understand what this has to do with Git.

Comment: `node` keeps track of a list of search paths where it will look for modules, which includes `node_modules`, it will not recursively look for a file with that name everywhere